# Sql query vba ADO

Tags: vba, excel

The sheet name is DATA on excel, using F4 properties in VBA instead of sheet1 I have changed it to sData.

My aql query is not returning any result.I need to extract a column from the Data Sheet of the same workbook in VBA.

My code is :

```
Sql = "Select productNumber from [shtData$] where produvtDesc = "&pDes&" "
'pDesc is a string variable that stores description.
```

Is this how we put the sheet name in sql query? I tried [Data$] as well but it doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't add any code concerning the i am assuming that you set up the connection correctly.

- use the sheet name you see in excel, not the F4 code `(name)`. Use it with a trailing `$` and square brackets like you did
- i assume `pDes` doesn't contain a string in quotes. So, add quotes around your where-criterium
- look [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) on how to set up an ado connection to excel
- alternatively, this example of an sql onto an Excel is working even if your actual ado connection refers to another database:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM [data$A1:E1000] IN 'C:\path\MyFile.xlsx' [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0]
  ```

**Edit:** For an xls you need different properties, as described in the link above.

- i assume your file is called `data.xls` and that it contains a sheet that is called `data`
- this works if stored in a string and then used as connection string:

  ```
  Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\data.xls;
  Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES";
  ```

  and paired with this sql

  ```
  Sql = "Select productNumber from [data$] where produvtDesc = '" & pDes & "'"
  ```
- since you want to use a dynamic path try

  ```
  myCon.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filepath & "\data.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
  ```

  They key is to escape the double quotes `"` with a 2nd `"`

Comment: So my sql becomes : select productNumber from [Data$] where productDesc = '"&pDesc&"' ".         In setting the connection,my connection is right but as you mentioned the path am getting the path dynamically ,storing in in a variable and then I want to put Data.xls,concatenation may be u can say.

Comment: So "Data Source=" &pathname& "Data.xls"&";",Is this right?

Comment: I don't know how to put the path, am getting a suntax error

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo on your pDesc variable. In the note you've called it 'pDesc' but in the SQL command string its called 'pDes'.

Also, Is it possible that you have whatever DBMS it is that you are using to be case sensitive when referring to table names (so should therefore be [DATA$])? I know most DBMS's default to case in-sensitive, but I believe it is possible to configure it to be case sensitive during the set up process...